# HTML5 video with alpha chanel in Safari

Tags: html, canvas, video

I've already seen a lot of examples, but none of them work in safari.

For example:

- https://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/
- https://simpl.info/videoalpha/
- http://www.sciencelifeny.com/transparency/transparency.html

Also I know about APNG but it is not supported in IE and Edge.
There is a seeThru library, but to work with it you need to create a mask. Is there a cross-browser solution?

Comment: Indeed Safari doesn't support webm, so they won't support the variant with alpha either which is used in the second link. However, the two other links use the canvas API to generate the alpha on the fly. This, Safari does support it, like most browsers. But in the first link, it seems that they use codecs Safari can't read. So this leaves us with actually only the third link as working example in Safari, but when they wrote it, autoplay was still a thing, while it's not anymore. So you need to go to your dev's tools and type `video.play()` to make it work...

Comment: Precisely, thanks, just looking through a lot of demos, I thought that safari so does not know how.

Comment: Although if you look at the source of the video, then there is also a mask.
http://www.sciencelifeny.com/transparency/video/compressed_stacked.mp4